# How to verify a string only contains letters, numbers, underscores, and dashes in java

Tags: java, string, input, naming-conventions

I have a project where I have to write the code to check if the input string begins with digit, letter, $ or _ and if the input string has all alphabetical, numerical or _ chars.

Comment: read up on regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comment. You should try reading about [Regex](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm). I came up with  a basic regex which might be able to solve your issue:

```
^(\\d|[a-zA-Z$_]).([\\da-zA-Z_])*
    |                |
    |                --------------> Match (*) zero or more digit, alphabet or _
    |
    -------------------------------> Match (.) one digit, alphabet, $ or _
```

I tested it with the following code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("matches(_FooBar) : " + match("_FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches(1FooBar) : " + match("1FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches(12FooBar) : " + match("12FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches(aFooBar) : " + match("aFooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches($FooBar) : " + match("$FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches(-FooBar) : " + match("-FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches($$$FooBar) : " + match("$$$FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches(12FooBar) : " + match("12FooBar"));
    System.out.println("matches(12FooBar------) : " + match("12FooBar------"));
    System.out.println("matches($FooBar_) : " + match("$FooBar_"));
}

private static boolean match(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d|[a-zA-Z$_]).([\\da-zA-Z_])*");
    return p.matcher(input).matches();
}
```

It produces this output:

```
matches(_FooBar) : true
matches(1FooBar) : true
matches(12FooBar12) : true
matches(aFooBar) : true
matches($FooBar) : true
matches(-FooBar) : false
matches($$$FooBar) : false
matches(12FooBar) : true
matches(12FooBar------) : false
matches($FooBar_) : true
```